# How to add a next line inside a cell instead of next cell using EXCEL module in perl

Tags: perl

I am learning EXCEL module in perl. I am reading a file which has 4 lines. When i use Excel module it is print to next cell. Is there any way to print in same cell.
I have also tried adding "^@" symbol at the end of line and it is adding in same cell with extra character

Thanks in advance

file 1:

```
line 1  
line 2 
line 3 
line 4
```

```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
   my $WorkBook=Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('test.xls');
   my $Worksheet=$WorkBook->add_worksheet();
   my %data;
   open (INPUT,"file");
   my $line_no=1;
   while (<INPUT>) {
      $data{$line_no}=$_;
      $line_no=$line_no+1;
    }
    foreach my $i (keys %data) {
    $Worksheet->write("A$i",$data{$i});
    }
```

All syntax is taken care and snippet of code pasted here.

Comment: sorry updated with Excel module using Excel::Writer::XLSX

Comment: Added entire code

Comment: I have copied the code

Comment: Your question ins not clear. Do you want all the file content in a single cell or one line per cell? You are reading the file line by line and you insert each lines content into a new cell. If the syntax of your example is fixed this works. - You may want to chomp the lines, before inserting them into the cells though.

Comment: Hi Clamp my requirement is to read all lines and add in single cell. With the above scripot it is adding one line per cell. and yeah i am readding line by line

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole file in one cell, you don't need to read it line by line. You can read the file in one go, then insert it into your worksheet. I added the format as suggested by the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#set_text_wrap()). It might not be necessary ( I don't have EXCEL to test it, LibreOffice renders it fine without the format).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $WorkBook=Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('test.xls');
my $Worksheet=$WorkBook->add_worksheet();

open (my $in,'<',"file.txt")or die "could not open file.txt: $!";
my $file_content = do { local $/; <$in> };

my $format = $WorkBook->add_format();
$format->set_text_wrap();

$Worksheet-> write("A1",$file_content,$format);
```

In case you want to add only lines selected by line numbers, you can read the lines into an array. The `<>` operator returns a list of lines when used in list context. I prepended an element to `@lines` here, so your line numbers start with 1. Then use an array slice and join it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my @line_numbers =  (4,5);

my $WorkBook=Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('test.xls');
my $Worksheet=$WorkBook->add_worksheet();

open (my $in,'<',"file.txt")or die "could not open file.txt: $!";

my @lines = ('', <$in>);
my $content = join ('',@lines[@line_numbers]);

my $format = $WorkBook->add_format();
$format->set_text_wrap();
$Worksheet-> write("A1",$content,$format);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another doubt if we want to add only selected lines like 4th and 5th line in one cell do we need modify my file ha ?